# I need help. My ASP.Net MVC Logout not working

Tags: c#, html

When I log in, I am unable to log out. The session doesn't clear and I don't know why? When I click on Logout, it doesn't do anything. I want to click Logout and then it switches the navbar to show Register/Login. But it doesn't clear the session. In the Logout Method in UserController.cs, I've tried `Session.Clear() Session.Abandon() FormsAuthentication.Signout()` Below is my Controller
**UserController.cs**

```
  // Login POST
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(UserLogin login, string ReturnUrl = "")
    {
        string message = "";
        using (SocialEntities dc = new SocialEntities())
        {
            var v = dc.tblUsers.Where(a => a.Email == 
                          login.Email).FirstOrDefault();
            if (v != null)
            {
                if (string.Compare(HashPassword.Hash(login.Password), 
                                                    v.Password) == 0)
                {
                    int timeout = login.RememberMe ? 525600 : 20; // 525600 
                                                               min = 1 year
                    var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(login.Email, 
                                                login.RememberMe, timeout);
                    string encrypted = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
                    var cookie = new 
                  HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encrypted);
                    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(timeout);
                    cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

                    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(ReturnUrl))
                    {
                        return Redirect(ReturnUrl);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Session["Email"] = login.Email;
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                message = "Error";
            }


        }
        ViewBag.Message = message;
        return View();
    }

    // Logout
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Logout()
    {
        Session.Clear();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

And here is my **_Layout.schtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Social Network</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data- 
                 target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            @Html.ActionLink("Social Network", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = 
 "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
                @*@Html.Partial("_loginPartial")*@          
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="float:right !important">
                @if (Session["Email"] != null)
                {
                    <li> <p style="color:red; margin-top:15px;">Hello, @Session["Email"] </p></li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Logout", "Index", "Home")</li>
                }
                else
                {
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Registration", "User")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Login", "Login", "User")</li>
                }
            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Keane, Inc.</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `FormsAuthentication.SignOut();`

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I have tried that as well and the same result.

Comment: Or `AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);` anyway, share the code of AccountController so we can see how you are logging in.

Comment: Ok I added the UserController

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what you have tried, rather than making people guess everything you've tried one by one. Link to any Stack Overflow posts you've attempted and show how you've attempted to implement the answers therein. This question is a common one and will likely get closed as a duplicate if we don't see that you've tried what's mentioned in the duplicates' answers.

Comment: maybe clear cookies